# Is there a way in Tableau server to limit the rows displayed but then download the complete data into a crosstab?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a large text table (about 200k records) that's generated from a custom SQL query.  I've added filters so users can limit the output, but the text table is still quite large, so rendering of the table is pretty slow.  I know that I can limit the rows displayed using a calculated field like Index().  However, what if I want to limit the rows displayed to the user, but still enable them to pull the full dataset?  In other words, lets say they filter by ID #123 and the text table has 5k records with ID #123.  I want to display at most 100 of these records in the dashboard and if they need the complete raw data, they can pull the 5k into a crosstab.  Currently, if I apply an Index to limit the rows displayed in the dashboard to 1k, they'll only be able to download 1k records to the dashboard.

Ultimately, the purpose is to make the raw data available, but make the experience using the dashboard a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate sheet purely for download. When downloading all of the records on the Detail shelf are exported - the fields don't need to be visible in the dashboard. Therefore you could create some form of dummy field - perhaps something simple like a SUM([Number of records]) - to display in the view with the remainder of the fields hidden on the Detail shelf. This means the view won't take an age to render but the fields will still export.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this seems to be a solution to hide some columns from the dashboard,  but I'm interested in limited the row count.  Would creating a dummy field solve that issue?

Comment: It should do, but I haven't tested. If your dummy field was something like IF FIRST()=0 THEN do something END that may restrict the records to only the first yet (hopefully) still enable the export of all.

Comment: Note it's also the number of marks that dictates the slow rendering so removing columns is as beneficial as removing rows. Marks = rows * columns.